# Java- check if dataset from table already exists

Tags: java, database

I select the datasets with a button from my database table, but every time I click on the button it loads the same datasets I already have:

`public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {`
                `java.sql.Connection con;`

```
            try {
                con = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/lessons","root","");
                String query =" SELECT * FROM lessons";
                PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);

                while(rs.next())
                {
                    int lesson = rs.getInt("lessons");
                    String name= rs.getString("names");
                    String number= rs.getString("numbers");
                    model.addRow(new Object[]{lessons, names, numbers});

                    table.setVisible(true);
                }
```

I just want to print the datasets which are unique.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Why would it load a different dataset, based on this code?

Comment: @nitind for example I have 6 datasets in the table and every time I click on the button it loads the same 6 datasets I already displayed in the jtable and when I click once again I have 18,24... times the same dataset. I hope I can explain it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove all available rows before loading data to table

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)your_table.getModel();

 ... 

  model.setRowCount(0); // add this line

  while(rs.next()) {

     int lesson = rs.getInt("lessons");
     String name= rs.getString("names");
     String number= rs.getString("numbers");

     ....
     model.addRow(new Object[]{lessons, names, numbers});
  }
```

Comment: that is incredible it really works!! But when I have duplicates in the table how can I show this unique datasets?? @Madushan Perera

Comment: What do you mean by duplicates ? you have duplicate rows in your database ??

Comment: Then you can filter them by your sql query . [#DISTINCT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) , [#GROUPBY()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Comment: Thank you so much!! @Madushan Perera